# Is Django's "Model" API thread-safe?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, thread-safety

Specifically, I'm only talking about modifying separate instances of a Model (not sharing the same exact instance) across threads. But is it safe to be calling save() from one thread, while multiple other threads are invoking Model.objects.query() or Model.objects.get() for example?

Comment: what do you call safe? and and what db backend and transaction isolation level are we talking about?

Comment: MySql + READ UNCOMMITTED. By "safe," I mostly mean that in-memory Django data structures will not be corrupted (i.e., due to shared global state being modified from multiple threads) - essentially, I am only worried about the class of error that could crop up specifically with python threads, not with say running multiple independent servers concurrently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as we speak about save versus get and query, you are safe, since distinct querysets objects are involved. In fact, every `query`, `filter`, `get` call and so on creates a new queryset instance, and do not modify any previously existed object.

But obviously, you can run into issues when accessing/modifying same db record simultaneously from several threads/clients so on.

As I remember, to deal with database updates consistency, in oracle db and mysql inndodb with disabled autocommit there is a `select for update` statement.